# Remove duplicates from a Java List

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8

I want to remove duplicates from a list like bellow

```
List<DataRecord> transactionList =new ArrayList<DataRecord>();
```

where the DataRecord is a class

```
public class DataRecord {
    [.....]
    private String TUN;
```

and the TUN should be unique

Comment: If you have overrided `equals` method for `DataRecord` to compare the String TUN, you could use new `Set<>(transactionList)` to remove duplicates.

Comment: @charkoul does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @xenteros I tried the first solution but the duplicate values (based on TUN) did not remove(I have checked the results using the size() method)

Comment: They won't be removed from this list. It'll create another without duplicates. It's much more efficient in terms of time complexity

Comment: @xenteros I know but noDuplicatesList.size() = transactionList.size()

Comment: Could you try the second approach?

Comment: Or just override the hashCode too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possbile solutions.

The first one is to override the equals method. Simply add:

```
public class DataRecord {
    [.....]
    private String TUN; 

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof DataRecord) {
            DataRecord that = (DataRecord) o;
            return Objects.equals(this.TUN, that.TUN);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
           return Objects.hashCode(TUN);
    }
}
```

Then, the follwing code will remove duplicates:

```
List<DataRecord> noDuplicatesList = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(transactionList));
```

When you can't override the equals method, you need to find a workaround. My idea is the following:

1. Create a helper `HashMap<String, DataRecord>` where keys will be TUNs.
2. Create an `ArrayList` out of `values()` set.

Implementation:

```
Map<String, DataRecord> helper = new HashMap<>();
for (DataRecord dr : transactionList) {
    helper.putIfAbsent(dr.getTUN(), dr);
}
List<DataRecord> noDuplicatesList = new ArrayList<>(helper.values());
```

Comment: If using Java8+ you can use `Map.putIfAbsent(K, V)` in your second suggestion.

Comment: @t4dohx that's a good point

Comment: @xenteros the second approach works perfect.Thank you